# How to fix "node.decodeJpeg is not a function" (tensorflow.js)?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I use [this](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/1.2.6/#node.decodeImage) link to decode an image and get 3d tensor. Code bellow:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
let node = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const { Image } = require('image-js');

async function getImage() {
    let image = await Image.load('/path/to/image.jpg');
    return image;
}

async function loadModel() {
    let m = await tf.loadLayersModel('path/to/model.json')
    return m;
}

let model = loadModel();

model.then(async function (res) {
    const img = await getImage();
    const imgTensor = node.decodeImage(img, 1, 'int32', false);
    console.log(imgTensor);
}, function (err) {
       console.log(err);
   });
```

And when i use node.decodeImage() i get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: node.decodeImage is not a function`. If i use tf.node.decodeImage() i get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'decodeImage' of undefined`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my mistake, correct form will be like: node.node.decodeImage(...)